# Merging leaves from many ROOT files into one

Tags: c++, data-science, physics, root-framework

I have several thousand CERN ROOT files, each with the same TTree structure. Each tree has a branch with 10 variables, of which I only want two. Currently, I iterate over every ROOT file, and store it in a TChain. Then, I iterate over every file in the TChain, and use GetLeaf to copy the two leaves I want into a TNtuple. I end up with a TNtuple with the two leaves that I want which hold all of the values from the files. The code, however, is very slow and rather messy. Is there a cleaner and/or faster way to do this?

Comment: Yes! I wasn't aware there's a tag for this.

Comment: Click on the tag, there is maybe a question that will help you.

Comment: Is just using the TChain as is (with GetEntry, Draw, …) not doing the job (i.e. do you actually need to copy to a TNtuple?). Usually that does the job quite nicely. If many files is unpractical, the `hadd` command line application (ships with root) usually does a neat job at merging the entries of tress with the same name and structure from different files (as they come out of grid/batch systems) into one.